# Joomla site not processing through php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla, vhosts

At work I migrated a joomla site to our development server to work on. Our server is set up to have the htaccess stuff go in the vhosts file and not load htaccess from the site locations.

The joomla site is not redirecting and the pages are spiting out the php code as text!

I ran config test and restrated apache.

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/thejoomlasite.com/httpdocs
ServerName thejoomlasite.com
ServerAlias thejoomlasite.com.devserver.olddev.local
ServerAlias thejoomlasite.com.dev
ServerAlias thejoomlasite.com.devsite.com
ServerAlias thejoomlasite.devsite.com

CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/thejoomlasite.com/log/access_log combined
ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/thejoomlasite.com/log/error_log

ServerAdmin webmaster@myserver.com

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/thejoomlasite.com/httpdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    # Anything you'd put in an .htaccess goes here
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.168
    Options -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
        # Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
        ##
        # @package      Joomla
        # @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
        # @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
        ##

        ##
        # READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
        #
        # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
        # with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
        # be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
        # your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
        # beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
        # it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
        ##

        ## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
        # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
        #Options +FollowSymLinks
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

        ## Mod_rewrite in use.

        RewriteEngine On

        ## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
        # If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
        # This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
        #
        # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
        # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
        # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
        # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
        # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
        RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
        #
        ## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

        ## Begin - Custom redirects
        #
        # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
        # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
        # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
        #
        ## End - Custom redirects

        ##
        # Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
        # is not directly related to physical file paths.
        # Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
        ##

        RewriteBase /

        ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
        #
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        #
        # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
        # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
        # and the request is for something within the component folder,
        # or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
        # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
        # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
        #
        ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what the home page is spitting out

```php
mark('afterLoad') : null; // Instantiate the application. $app =
JFactory::getApplication('site'); // Initialise the application.
$app->initialise(); // Mark afterIntialise in the profiler. JDEBUG ?
$_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null; // Route the application.
$app->route(); // Mark afterRoute in the profiler. JDEBUG ?
$_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null; // Dispatch the application.
$app->dispatch(); // Mark afterDispatch in the profiler. JDEBUG ?
$_PROFILER->mark('afterDispatch') : null; // Render the application.
$app->render(); // Mark afterRender in the profiler. JDEBUG ?
$_PROFILER->mark('afterRender') : null; // Return the response. echo
$app;
```

Comment: If the website is simply spiting the code top to bottom, Then make sure that PHP is promptly installed there. Try _php -v_ to see the php version installed. All make sure that you have provided the php handler in your _apache conf file_.

Comment: PHP is installed and working we have other development sites working just fine.

Comment: Check what is defined in your config.php for the parameter _public $host_ . Also what version of Joomla you are using ? Just go through the [system requirements](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html) from this link. Make sure _public $host_ is defined as _localhost_

Comment: put PHP handler `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php` outside of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, seems like it's not enabled on the dev server

Comment: It is Joomla 2.5 and the server meets all the required conditions.

Comment: I looked more closely and noticed the whole php page wasn't outputted. I did an echo in index.php to be sure. for some reason after that it started working. Removed the echo and it is still working...